# Dynamic Form to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I'm trying to make a log of cars going in and out of a parking lot.

The car info is retrieved from a database and is working fine. The problem I'm having is getting the in/out times to store into the database. In a previous page I had done it so that the form was separate from the table and the input info would be updated but for this page I need to have a dynamic amount of fields varying on the cars in the database. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but here is my code, the data is not being sent or stored in the data base.

```
<h3>Update Car</h3>
<form action="carLog.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Car Log</legend>

    <?php //This prints out the car log data

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM carLog";
      $result = $databaseConnection->query($sql);

      echo "<table class='TFtable' border='1' style='width':100%>"; //starts the table tag
      echo "<tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Vehicle</td>
              <td>Licence Plate</td>
              <td>In</td>
              <td>Out</td>
              <td>In</td>
              <td>Out</td>
              <td>Comments</td>
            </tr>"; //sets headings

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //loops for each result

        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['vehicle']."</td>
                <td>".$row['plate']. "</td>
                <td><input type='text' size='5' maxlength='5' name='inTime' value='".$row['inTime']."' id='inTime' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='outTime' value='".$row['outTime']."' id='outTime' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='inTime2' value='".$row['inTime2']."' id='inTime2' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='outTime2' value='".$row['outTime2']."' id='outTime2' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='comments' value='".$row['comments']."' id='comments' /></td>
              </tr>";

      }
      echo "</table>"; //closes the table
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />                
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The database connection is fine and working. Here is the php that handles the post:

```
if (isset($_POST['Save'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $vehicle = $_POST['car'];
  $plate = $_POST['plate'];
  $inTime = $_POST['inTime'];
  $outTime = $_POST['outTime'];
  $inTime2 = $_POST['inTime2'];
  $outTime2 = $_POST['outTime2'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments'];
  $query = "UPDATE carLog SET inTime = '$inTime', outTime = '$outTime', inTime2 = '$inTime2', outTime2 = '$outTime2' WHERE plate = '$plate'";

  $databaseConnection->query($query);
```

Comment: on a side note, my form fields are coming out wayyyy bigger than necessary and adding the size='4' attribute inside the input field isn't helping, ideas?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: There are links in my previous comment.

Comment: i assume u refer to the second code segment?

Comment: Pass them as array. Also pass the unique ID so it can be easily processed in your php file.

Comment: suggest put a few debug bits in there so you can see what's going on. e.g. is the post data as expected: var_dump($_POST), what does the database say about your query: var_dump the result of the database query. etc until you find what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Note:

- You only have five (5) input fields inside your `while()` loop, but you are trying to process eight (8) input fields in your `carLog.php`. So it will return `undefine variables` error.
- Pass the input fields in array.
- Inside the loop, hide the primary id of each car/vehicle in a hidden input (also in array).

Add this inside your `while()` loop:

```
/* ASSUMING vehicle_id IS THE PRIMARY ID OF YOUR carLog TABLE; JUST REPLACE IT WITH THE RIGHT COLUMN NAME */
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'.$row["vehicle_id"].'">';
```

You have to add `[]` in your input's `name` tags.

```
<td><input type='text' name='outTime[]' .....
```

Do it to the rest of your inputs.

Then on your `carLog.php` file, which process the input (at least use 
[`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)). We will be checking each input using `for()` loop:

```
if (isset($_POST['Save'])){

  for($x = 0; $x< count($_POST["hidden_id"]); $x++){

    $vehicleid = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['hidden_id'][$x]);
    $inTime = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['inTime'][$x]);
    $outTime = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['outTime'][$x]);
    $inTime2 = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['inTime2'][$x]);
    $outTime2 = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['outTime2'][$x]);
    $comments = $databaseConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['comments'][$x]);

    $query = "UPDATE carLog SET inTime = '$inTime', outTime = '$outTime', inTime2 = '$inTime2', outTime2 = '$outTime2' WHERE vehicle_id = '$vehicleid'";

    $databaseConnection->query($query);

  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET Save */
```

Since you are using `mysqli_*` already, consider using the [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) approach.

Comment: so   *_real_escape_string will prevent sql injections? or do i still need to use other methods?

Comment: Yes, it does protect your from SQL injections. But `*_real_escape_string` has more work to do, applying it on each variable, compare to prepared statement, where it will sanitize each parametize variables for you. You can take a look at the links I have provided - [How to prevent SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more info. So did my answer work for you?